# Awk isn't taking bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I found this command to work great:

```
awk -v "/mallory:/,/end-config/ {next} 1" /filename.txt
```

It takes everything in a file like this:

```
alice:
 config option 1
 config option 2
 end-config

mallory:          <--- Line gets deleted
 config option 1  <--- Line gets deleted
 config option 2  <--- Line gets deleted
 end-config       <--- Line gets deleted

bob:
 config option 1
 config option 2
 end-config
```

and only deletes the config block for mallory.

So now I wanted to define this in a bash script, so username could be a bash variable. I did this:

```
#!/bin/bash
username="mallory"
awk -v username="$username" "/username:/,/end-config/ {next} 1" /file.txt
```

Guess what. It doesn't remove anything. The output matches the file I started with. What gives? I imported my variable correctly, right?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use

```
#!/bin/bash
username="mallory"
awk -v  "/${username}:/,/end-config/ {next} 1" /file.txt
```

Remember that the shell will do shell interpolation before the program gets to AWK, so `${username}` will  be replaced by `mallory`.  To be more safe, you might want to use

```
#!/bin/bash
username="mallory"
awk -v '/'"${username}"':/,/end-config/ {next} 1' /file.txt
```

which will ensure that the awk program is protected from any other shell interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The `/foo/,/bar/` is the range of addresses where your `{next}` statement will work. And, addresses must be literals. Geekosaur's answer does work with a bit of tweaking:

```
awk -v username="mallory" '
    $0 ~ (username ":"),/end-config/ {next}
    1' filename.txt
```

The `1` is needed for `awk` to do anything. A better way may be:

```
awk -v username="mallory" '
    $0 ~ (username ":"),/end-config/ {next}
    {print $0}' filename.txt
```

Which states that your printing the line `{print $0}` if you don't skip it via the `{next}` statement. Awk prints the line if given no other commands and it returns a *true* (non-zero) value.

Comment: Instead of {print $0} we could use {print} for less clutter.  It is more explicit than the lonely true pattern (1) with its implicit print

Answer (score 0):

```
"/username:/,/end-config/ {next}"
```

`username` will be literal there.  To match against a variable, you have to use an explicit pattern match:

```
awk -v username="mallory" '
    $0 ~ (username ":"),/end-config/ {next}
    1'
```

Answer (score 0):

bit shorter with sed - save the following into file e.g. confdel.sh

```
sed "/^$1:/,/end-config/d"
```

and use it like:

```
bash confdel.sh mallory < config_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`/username:/` matches exactly the string You have written and nothing to do with the environment variable, but awk can read the environment variables. I would suggest:

```
username=mallory
awk '$0 == ENVIRON["username] ":",/end-config/ {next} 1' /file.txt
```

Actually this is not the nicest solution, as in the result there is double empty lines. So if `username=mallory` is set, then the result is:

```
alice:
 config option 1
 config option 2
 end-config


bob:
 config option 1
 config option 2
 end-config
```

But maybe it is ok for You.